# Objective-C - Is there any way to use any class (UIView) as a Protocol on another object?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I've been experimenting in Objective-C with some rather peculiar concepts.

Below is an example:
Essentially I have an object called "theFilter" that should get all the messages plus "Some_More_Messages" from another object "theSender". Instances of Filter are meant to play filter on any number of instances, all of a different Class. Based on some criteria, it sends messages in the "Some_More_Messages" Protocol to some other object while all others just take the standard path.

```
Filter<Some_More_Messages> *theFilter;
```

For example I want to have this filter instance thing in front of an UIView instance and I need my "Filter" object to be able to receive all messages that UIView implements. Something like:

```
Filter<UIView,Some_More_Messages> *theFilter;
```

But I can't go on and create Protocols for each class I need for filter for. This is to get the compiler to stop complaining and to get autocompletion and everything else.

Any ideas?

PS. Inside the code for "theSender" I never refer to the UIView instance directly but instead talk to its "filterInstance" and send it "Some_More_Messages" than the UIView instance knows. The stuff that it knows it executes, and all the other selectors are redirected to some other instance.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a proxy object, and if so you want to read [Message Forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) in the Runtime Guide. Also see [`NSProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [`forwardingTargetForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:)

```
@interface Filter : NSObject /*NSProxy*/ <FilterProtocol>

@property UIView *view;

+ (UIView<FilterProtocol> *)filterWithView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@implementation

+ (UIView<FilterProtocol> *)filterWithView:(UIView *)view {
    return (UIView<FilterProtocol> *)[[self alloc] initWithView:view];
}

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.view = view;
    }
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([self.view respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return self.view;
    }

    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}

- (void)someFilterProtocolMethod {}

@end
```

---

```
 UIView<FilterProtocol> *filteredView = [Filter filterWithView:view];
 [filteredView addSubview:otherView]; // call addSubview on view
 [filteredView someFilterProtocolMethod]; // call someFilterProtocolMethod on filter object
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This is a good idea, but a bad implementation, check [Bryan Cheng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054079/1904287) for the correct implementation.

---

I think you're trying to achieve multiple inheritance. While Objective-C doesn't support that, you can mimic it by having an instance of `UIView` and forward unhandled messages to it.

You must forward the NSInvocations to the `UIView`, like this:

```c
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        // Try to use our version of the selector
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    } else {
        // But if we don't have that method, delegate it to the UIView
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.view];
    }
}
```

You can also fool other objects by overriding `respondsToSelector:`, `isKindOfClass:` and some other methods to make it look like you're in fact a UIView. Read more about this advanced technique in the [Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html)

BTW, if you just don't want it to crash, but don't need to actually forward the message to an internal `UIView`, then make the `respondsToSelector:` method return YES if it's a `UIView` method, but don't do anything on the `forwardInvocation:` bit.

Comment: first check is always false, and you also have to override `methodSignatureForSelector:` to get it working

Comment: and do nothing in `forwardInvocation:` is very bad. it need to set a valid return value to invocation object or throw exception to indicate return a value is not possible.

Comment: I have to admit that I've never needed this myself yet, I just wanted to point him in the right direction. So I just linked your answer, and upvoted you ;)